# Pegar ID do banco de dados ao selecionar opção no spinner?

Tags: android, sqlite

Geralmente eu pego o ID de um objeto selecionado/clicado com o `onItemClickListener`, mas ele não funciona com o `Spinner`.

Eu tentei dessa forma:

```
spn.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
       test1 = position;
       test2 = (int) id;
       test3 = view.getId();
   }

   @Override
   public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
   }
});
```

Também sem sucesso, ele me retorna apenas a posição dos itens dentro do *spinner*, e não o ID do banco de dados.

Alguma ideia?

**Edit**: Vale a pena mencionar que isso tudo está dentro de um `onItemClickListener` de um *Custom List View*, e o *Spinner* está num *Custom Dialog* a parte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o método [`getSelectedItem`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getSelectedItem%28%29) para obter o valor de um item selecionado.

Crie a seguinte classe *SpinnerObject*:

```
public class SpinnerObject {

    private  int databaseId;
    private String databaseValue;

    public SpinnerObject ( int databaseId , String databaseValue ) {
        this.databaseId = databaseId;
        this.databaseValue = databaseValue;
    }

    public int getId () {
        return databaseId;
    }

    public String getValue () {
        return databaseValue;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString () {
        return databaseValue;
    }

}
```

Agora você vai ter que criar a lista da seguinte forma:

```
public List < SpinnerObject> getAllLabels(){
    List < SpinnerObject > labels = new ArrayList < SpinnerObject > ();
    // Seleciona todas as consultas
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LABELS;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // Loop através de todas as linhas e adicionando à lista
    if ( cursor.moveToFirst () ) {
        do {
            labels.add ( new SpinnerObject ( cursor.getString(0) , cursor.getString(1) ) );
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // Fecha conexão
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    return labels;
}
```

Agora que você tem a lista de objetos com os valores e os ids, você carrega o *Spinner* da seguinte maneira:

```
private void loadSpinnerDataHama() {
    // database handler
    DatabaseSpinner db = new DatabaseSpinner(getApplicationContext()); 
    List <SpinnerObject> lables = db.getAllLabels();
    // Criando adaptador para o spinner
    ArrayAdapter<SpinnerObject> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<SpinnerObject>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lables);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    // Anexando adaptador de dados para o spinner
    spn.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
}
```

O *spinner* exibirá os valores, apesar de terem seus ids (a partir do banco de dados) também.

Para recuperar o ID do item selecionado:

```
int itemId = Integer.parseInt(((SpinnerObject) spn.getSelectedItem()).getId());
```

[Referência](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14331175/load-from-spinner-sqlite-with-text-and-value)

Comment: Olá bom amigo! Obrigado pelo seu tempo e resposta. Ele está me retornando a String com o nome do produto, eu precisava do ID, você sabe se eu consigo o ID através deste método?

Comment: Novamente, obrigado pela ajuda, mas ainda não está funcionando. Eu estou recebendo esse erro:        _java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to android.os.Message_

E também não apareceu a opção .getId(); aqui, apenas getData();

Comment: Infelizmente não, ele retorna apenas o nome do produto, e não o ID do banco de dados. Este é um dos problemas mais difíceis que já encontrei no android! EDIT: não vi seu último post, vou testar de novo!

Comment: O que seria o SpinnerObject? Eu não tenho essa classe, se eu criá-la o que eu deveria colocar dentro dela?

Comment: Estou obtendo este erro ainda: _java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to spinnerobject.SpinnerObject_ 

:(

Comment: por que será que está sendo tão difícil? Será um bug do android? será que se eu atualizar o android studio isso para? XD

Comment: @DiegoFortes Não é bug não :D... editei a resposta e coloquei por completo os passos a seguir.

Comment: cara, obrigado por tudo mas infelizmente ainda não vai. Tá me dando uma grande dor de cabeça já isso, vou ter que ver depois com calma... Eu fiz todos os passos e também chequei a referência, mas não funciona de jeito nenhum. O problema agora é que aparece tudo vazio no Spinner, não mostra meus itens cadastrados; e, se não fosse o suficiente, ele ainda não mostra o ID. XD tem que ter algum jeito mais fácil ou eu estou fazendo mt errado

Comment: CARA, eu descobri por que não tá funcionando.... quando eu chamo minha função SQL eu só to chamando uma coluna, a coluna Nome, então é impossível retornar o ID. Tudo isso que você postou tá certo, mas existe uma forma bem mais simples, essa: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20822515/how-to-get-the-id-of-selected-item-in-a-spinner

muito obrigado por toda a ajuda!!!!